# awk print pattern matched lines, and if a line with pattern1 has pattern2, then print line with pattern1 and nth line after as a single line

Tags: awk, sed

I currently have the output of a log, like the following.

```
20200124_075926.795633 [24_1859] [ERROR  ] [PID] error running program:
...
...
actual error message from n lines below
...
20200124_075929.261693 [24_1859] [INFO   ] [PID] blah
20200124_075929.374937 [24_1859] [PERF   ] [PID] blah blah
20200124_075930.660998 [24_1859] [ERROR  ] [PID] some error:
20200124_075956.793528 [24_1859] [ERROR  ] [PID] error running program:
...
...
actual error message from n lines below
...
```

I am currently using the following to output lines of a log that contain error and fatal messages, striping the first two columns that contain a timestamp.

```bsh
awk '/\[[FATAL|ERROR].*] \[.*\]/ { print substr($0, index($0,$3)) }' filename
```

This produces the exact results I want (at least to summarise count occurrences).

```
[ERROR  ] [PID] error running program:
[ERROR  ] [PID] some error:
[ERROR  ] [PID] error running program:
```

Now I want to extend this to include the text for a line that was matched in the above IF the line contains the second pattern.

For example, if the line from the first pattern also contains "`error running program`" then include the line n lines below. Else print line and keep going.

```
[ERROR  ] [PID] error running program: actual error message from n lines below
[ERROR  ] [PID] some error:
[ERROR  ] [PID] error running program: actual error message from n lines below
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. I think your `awk` command contains a flawed regular expression, although it seemingly works because of the limited possibilities for the "severity" tag of your log lines. You use `[FATAL|ERROR]` to indicate that you want to match either the string `FATAL` or `ERROR` in the square brackets. However, `[...]` defines a character list, so your usage would mean "match any string starting with `[`, followed by any of `F`,`A`,`T`, `|`,`E`,`R` or `O`. It works here, but string alternatives should, if at all, be placed in round braces as in `(FATAL|ERROR)`.

Comment: To clarify the strings FATAL or ERROR may be found elsewhere in the line. What I'm looking for is the string beginning with `[` containing the string `FATAL`or `ERROR` and ending with `] `. But I'll amend the command and verify if still works.

Comment: The condition of the string `FATAL` or `ERROR` being between `[ ... ]` is already provided for by your specification of `\[` before your alternative, so replacing the `[ ... ]` around the alternative with round braces will not break the correct operation.

Comment: Question for clarification: Is the "actual error messages from n lines below" also preceded by the `<timestamp> ... [PID]` fields on each output line, and do you want to squash all of these output lines into one for the "summary output"?

Comment: The lines are not proceeded by `<timestamp> ... [PID]` the lines themselves are output of a subcommand which contains several lines of meta content, but also the error output of the command executed. I only need the error message itself, which is always a set number of lines below the initial log message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    sub(/\r$/,"")
    txt = substr($0, index($0,$3))
}
/\[(FATAL|ERROR)[^]]*] \[.*]/ {
    if ( /error running program:/ ) {
        pfx = txt OFS
        cnt = 4
    }
    else {
        cnt = 1
    }
}
cnt && !--cnt { print pfx txt; pfx="" }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
[ERROR  ] [PID] error running program: message from n lines below
[ERROR  ] [PID] some error:
[ERROR  ] [PID] error running program: message from n lines below
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm!